# Setting a background color below a certain element on a page - HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I would like to have two background colors on a page, with one color being above an element (e.g. picture, text) and the another color being below an element. Preferably, in HTML, CSS or JavaScript.

I know about CSS gradients, however, I would like the colors to always be below or above an element, no matter how big or small the page is.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Split the page into 2 giant divs and give each one its own background color. Just put your "trigger" element and the end of the first div. Everything from that element up will be one color and the rest will be another.

Comment: No...unless the div is a set distance from the top of the page...but that seems unlikely. Alternaively, some HTML & CSS in a demo for some context woudl be useful.

Comment: Please show us your code. https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to separate your content with two divs. Example (you can add some content in bg-one or bg-two to test) :

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-one,
.bg-two {
  padding: 1em;
}
.bg-one {
  background-color: pink;
}
.bg-two {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-one">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-two">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I didn't understand your question and if you want to change the color of the whole background past a certain element.

Edit: Here is another way to do something nice with jQuery (if it doesn't work in the iFrame, here is the codepen : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/VLNMzz ) >

```js
$(window).on('load scroll resize', function() {
  var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop(),
    breakPoint = $('#bg-two').offset().top,
    $body = $('body');
  if (scrollTop > breakPoint) {
    $body.css('background-color', 'orange');
  } else {
    $body.css('background-color', 'pink');
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: pink;
  transition: background-color .4s;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-one,
.bg-two {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-one">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-two" id="bg-two">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to absolute position a DIV and set background-color and z-index properties. I can give you example but I need more input on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But if I use an absolute DIV, will it still resize with the page and always take up the same amount of space?

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS:
     $("#element").css({ background-color:black; border-top:solid 2px #0000});

or in style file:

```
 element{
background-color: #fff;
border-top: solid 10px #000;  
color: #333;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The background of the page should be one color from this element up, and a different page background color for the remaining page. You are just putting colors on one element.

Answer (score -1):

You create a div with an absolute position to put it over your other element, in this case it's a red div with text.

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.text {
    background: #f00;
    height: 200px;
}

.blackScreen {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="text">
        nice text
    </div>
    <div class="blackScreen"></div>
</div>
```